# WP_Query "sortby" with separation titles

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add "separation titles" to a WordPress query currently ordered by a custom field.

At the moment, the result of the query looks like :

Honda Civic
Honda Accord
Toyota Corolla
Toyota Camry
Hyundai Accent
Hyundai Elantra

I would like the result to look like :

Honda
Honda Civic
Honda Accord

Toyota
Toyota Corolla
Toyota Camry

Hyundai
Hyundai Accent
Hyundai Elantra

The "orderby" of my query is working but I would like to know how I can "inject" a string before each makes.

Here is my query :

```
$args = array(
      'post_type' => vehicle,
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'meta_key' => 'make',
      'orderby' => 'make',
      'facetwp' => true,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to make the "make" custom field a taxonomy (category related to cars). As this is not only best practice but will suit your situation well.

From here you can apply code that looks like the following to get the desired effect.

```
    $makes = get_terms( 'make' ,  array('fields' => 'ids') );

foreach ($makes as $make) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => vehicle,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'make' => array($make),
        'facetwp' => true,
        );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
#all the code that you need to echo out presumably the titles and the break tag you are looking for and wp_reset_query(); e.t.c
}
```